# How to use a MySQL stored procedure that generates a random 8-char long key to encrypt data again each time a the user logs in

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, encryption, aes

I am working on a stored procedure in MySQL that is used to Login in a user for my polling application. I am trying to implement an algorithm that generates a new random 8-char long string that is being used as a new passphrase to re-encrypt data again.

In my particular case I am re-encrypting given answer-ids (aid) using this passphrase combined with AES. To re-encrypt the data that is already stored encrypted inside my database, the user provides his/her password to decrypt the 8-char long value that has already been stored inside the database. In other words the password is used to decrypt the old encryption-key so this key can be used to decrypt the answer-id of the question the user has voted on. Then the procedure generates a new 8-char long key to re-encrypt these answer-ids again each time the user has successfully logged in.

Unfortunately when I test my procedure, and I check the "vote" table I get NULL as the new encrypted answer id. I have done many attempts to correct this error and probably it has to do something with semantics but I haven't been able to solve it so far and I am puzzling very hard to find out what went wrong. The Login procedure calls another procedure that is responsible for extracting and decrypting already encrypted answer-ids, therefore it is using a while-loop that inserts data into a temporary table. Could you guys please help me out ?

In my opinion it is a slightly advanced procedure, maybe too advanced for my purposes. That's why I provided some comments that will lead you through all the steps being executed. This is my code:

**LoginUser procedure**

```
--------------------
-- LoginUser --
-- uname is stored encrypted by passwordhash, 
-- pw is stored encrypted by unamehash, 
-- key is encrypted by passwordhash, 
-- aid is encrypted by key 
--------------------
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS LoginUser;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE LoginUser(IN uname CHAR(64), IN pw CHAR(64))
BEGIN
-- declare variables
DECLARE validUser, validLogin, validCombination BOOLEAN default 0;
DECLARE encryptedUsername, oldEncryptedKey, newEncryptedKey, encryptedPassword VARBINARY(32);
DECLARE plainOldKey, plainNewKey CHAR(8);

-- set encrypted username
SET encryptedUsername = (SELECT AES_ENCRYPT(uname,SHA2(pw,256)));
-- check if username exists - returns 1 for true, 0 for false
SET validUser = (SELECT EXISTS(SELECT username FROM user WHERE username = encryptedUsername));

-- logic when valid user
IF (validUser = 1) THEN

    -- get pkey from user
    SET oldEncryptedKey = (SELECT pkey FROM user WHERE username = encryptedUsername);
    -- decrypt pkey using passwordhash
    SET plainOldKey = (SELECT AES_DECRYPT(oldEncryptedKey, SHA2(pw,256)));
    -- encrypt pw using plainOldKey
    SET encryptedPassword = (SELECT AES_ENCRYPT(pw,SHA2(uname,256)));
    -- check combination
    SET validCombination = (SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = encryptedUsername AND `password` = encryptedPassword));

    -- logic when valid combination
    IF(validCombination = 1) THEN
        -- set valid login to true
        SET validLogin = 1;
        -- generate a plainNewKey
        SET plainNewKey = (SELECT SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 8));
        -- set new encrypted key
        SET newEncryptedKey = (SELECT AES_ENCRYPT(plainNewKey,SHA2(pw,256)));
        -- call procedure to re-encrypt answer ids.
        CALL EncryptAidsAgain(plainOldKey,plainNewKey,encryptedUsername);

        -- update pkey from user table by newKey
        UPDATE user SET pkey = newEncryptedKey WHERE username = encryptedUsername;

    END IF;

END IF;

SELECT validLogin;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

**EncryptAidsAgain procedure**

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS EncryptAidsAgain;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE EncryptAidsAgain(IN oldKeyValue CHAR(8), IN newKeyValue CHAR(8), IN encryptedUsername VARBINARY(32))
BEGIN

DECLARE i, answered INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE encryptedAid, newEncryptedAid VARBINARY(32);
DECLARE plainAid CHAR(7);

-- create temporary table to store aids
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE aids(oldEncryptedAid VARBINARY(32));

-- get amount of given answers
SET answered = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vote WHERE username = encryptedUsername);

-- perform while loop
WHILE i < answered DO
    -- insert single aid in temporary table aids
    INSERT INTO aids (oldEncryptedAid) SELECT aid FROM vote WHERE username = encryptedUsername LIMIT i, 1;
    -- retrieve stored aid from aids
    SET encryptedAid = (SELECT oldEncryptedAid FROM aids LIMIT i, 1);
    -- decrypt stored aid from aids using oldKeyValue
    SET plainAid = (SELECT AES_DECRYPT(encryptedAid, SHA2(oldKeyValue,256)));
    -- set new encrypted aid
    SET newEncryptedAid = (SELECT AES_ENCRYPT(plainAid,SHA2(newKeyValue,256)));
    -- update table vote (aid)
    UPDATE vote SET aid = newEncryptedAid WHERE username = encryptedUsername AND aid = encryptedAid;
    -- increase i
    SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;

DROP TABLE aids;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

**test results**

When call the LoginUser procedure multiple times each time the key updates well:

```
mysql> select * from user;
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| username         | password         | pkey             | ip                                                               |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| EÞ¯k·\â¥çJ¤EÃîP  | EÞ¯k·\â¥çJ¤EÃîP  | 6░ÛõaÇªhpK║ÔäV   | 26b92be7c4ad202f842d1755c3db56f25b39c54c51cc56642b8f14ba4bda793d |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> call LoginUser("test4","test4");
+------------+
| validLogin |
+------------+
|          1 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> select * from user;
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| username         | password         | pkey             | ip                                                               |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| EÞ¯k·\â¥çJ¤EÃîP  | EÞ¯k·\â¥çJ¤EÃîP  | ┴O¥╝Îìöãñ#='¹    | 26b92be7c4ad202f842d1755c3db56f25b39c54c51cc56642b8f14ba4bda793d |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But when I login the user multiple times, the new encrypted answer-ids go NULL

```
mysql> select * from vote;
+-----+------------------+------+------------------+
| vid | username         | qid  | aid              |
+-----+------------------+------+------------------+
|   3 | EÞ¯k·\â¥çJ¤EÃîP |    2 | ðlözaò3OîÙW▓B═Ï |
|   4 | EÞ¯k·\â¥çJ¤EÃîP |    1 | z)ı╝├║%~╝V&7@"─V |
+-----+------------------+------+------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> call LoginUser("test4","test4");
+------------+
| validLogin |
+------------+
|          1 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> select * from vote;
+-----+------------------+------+------+
| vid | username         | qid  | aid  |
+-----+------------------+------+------+
|   3 | EÞ¯k·\â¥çJ¤EÃîP |    2 | NULL |
|   4 | EÞ¯k·\â¥çJ¤EÃîP |    1 | NULL |
+-----+------------------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Thank you very much in advance, if you have any tips for a better encryption policy they are very welcome!

Comment: I just happen to solve my problem! The NULL values where caused by another procedure i.e. the AddNewVote procedure I didn't mention in my post. It received a wrong input for the AES encryption algorithm that was set up to encrypt the answer-id

Comment: `FROM aids LIMIT i, 1` is not guaranteed to give you the next row (as tables have no inherent order). You may want to check out [cursors](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html). You could also just update all rows at the same time, something like `update votes set aid = AES_ENCRYPT(AES_DECRYPT(aid, SHA2(oldKeyValue,256))),SHA2(newKeyValue,256))) where username = ...`. Also note that reencrypting the votes won't make them more secure, and that, while you do all this encrypting, you send a cleartext password to the procedure, which is like leaving a window open in fort knox.